# jQueryMobile header, footer and panel templates

Tags: templates, jquery-mobile, include

I've checked some answers about creating a multi-page jQueryMobile page in where you can "load dynamically" header and footer sections into divs. But sincerely, they don't work at all.

Maybe those solutions works with a simple header with a logo, and a footer with text, but in cases of complex header, footer and lateral panels, there's some problems with the page creation.

I've playing around with pagebeforeshow, pageinit and other events, and with the triggers create and create page, but nothing works. So I beg help here to a solution for everybody that works ;-)

Let's take a complex jQueryMobile page like this template Lemonado (http://sergshepelevich.com/lemonado/)

You can see header, footer and panels.

I'm trying to create a multipage jQueryMobile pages, because if not, there's too much "header" section to include and paste in each html. Also, I'm looking for a "template solution" because if not, I have to paste a big portion of data in each data-page.

With this solution above I almost get this working, but:

1) When you click the panel to appear , it comes with a visual mistake/glitch

2) When you go to a second page and come to the first one, the panels don't work

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(){        
    if ($("#"+$(this).attr("id")).find('[id="header"]').html().length == 0) {   

        $.mobile.activePage.find('[id="header"]').load("include_header.html", function(){ 
            $(this).parent().trigger('create');
        }); 
        $.mobile.activePage.find('[id="left_panel"]').load("include_left_panel.html", function(){ 
            $(this).parent().trigger('create');
        });  
});
```

I've changing and changing things (triggers, events...) but when I fix something I break other thing.

So here's the deal: to create a solution to load the header, footer and panels section, and when you change to a second page (data-role page), the panels and everything works.

Comment: Use external panel(s), header and footer. Load them once to work on all pages.

Comment: Omar, as I explained, I tried that as you can see in my code, but panels or header does not work when you move between pages.

Comment: are you using jQM 1.4?

Comment: Yes, 1.4.0, Lemonado has that

Comment: As far as i am aware once the index.html is loaded which is usually your first page all your scripts are loaded for all pages. What you are doing here if i am correct is reloading the scripts at every page change. which seems a waste. I only have duplicate page scripts on every page as i have a cordova app i am building and if on resume they are not on the index page it can reload the correct scripts once for all pages.